# Does ROS 2 support Intel i7 CPU?

Tags: ros, cpu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For Running ROS 2: Do in need a amd CPU or is Intel i7 ok.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/406059/does-ros-2-support-intel-i7-cpu?/) by [Ruedscher](https://answers.ros.org/users/116969/ruedscher/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2022-09-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-09-07**:
I'd be interested to hear what made you ask this question.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You heard it totally wrong! ROS does no  discrimination!

**So yes, ROS 2 support Intel i7 CPU.**

---

Originally posted by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) with karma: 1744 on 2022-09-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 1):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ran M1 using docker on arm64, intel i7, amd, raspberry pi and some platforms using ros2. Yeah, they support those CPUs. It's the OS issue though. I tried windows 8 and I didn't have any luck. I haven't tried ros2 on windows 10/11. I'm still having hard time to install mac intel (maybe because I didn't put much efforts).

Generally, you can run ros2 on any CPU. Just watch out for OS architecture

---

Originally posted by [kak13](https://answers.ros.org/users/71412/kak13/) with karma: 113 on 2022-09-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-09-07**:
I have used ROS2 with Windows 10, it worked (at least a few months ago)